# Adding a link in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm designing a website with php and mysql. I have a table that was created with mysql that has a product name, a number, and a description and I was wondering if I can add a column in the table that can be a link to a different website. For example a column that says "buy from amazon" and that link go to an amazon.com page that has the product. I know I can do this with a php table but I would rather have a mysql table.

Comment: Um, sure. Why couldn't you have this?

Comment: I mean I can put valchar and then directly put in the link. However I don't want the exact url. I want to have it say something else and just go to the link

Comment: Well you could create two new columns or a separate table to pull the url/text pair.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a column with the value of varchar or text. You shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: How would I change the name of the link? I don't want to have the www.blahblahblah/blahblah/blahblah.com associated with it

Answer (score 0):

First you need to modify the database table schema to include a new column for holding the item's ASIN (the amazon product number).  Then, in your display code, you loop through the table, and for each item, you'll output a link, properly formatted, that links to the Amazon product page.

If you are a beginner, you'll need to learn several things:

1. How to modify a MySQL table schema.  At least three options - using PHP code, using mysql command line, using phpmyadmin
2. How to modify your PHP code that is currently displaying your data table to take into account the new column
3. How Amazon product URLs are structured

Comment: I just used Amazon as an example. I'm not sure which site I will reference yet

Answer (score 0):

I also implemented a similar concept.

First I added 2 columns to my table, `link` and `link_name` both of which were `varchar()` of suitable size. `link` stored the `href` or the actual address while `link_name` stored the text to be shown for the link.

I did an `XMLHttpRequest()` from my `.js` file and it returned a `json` parsed data back.

Then I added the following in my `.js` file

```
for ( var k in jsonData )
{
 var my_row = '<td><a href="' + "http://" + jsonData[k].link + '"' + ">" + jsonData[k].link_name + "</a></td>";
// other code
}
```

It worked for me !